# Definition of a relation generated by R - Can someone explain this definition and give a simple example?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, definition, relations, equivalence-relations

From a footnote in Rotman's Algebraic topology:

https://s3.postimg.org/i2739kx8z/QQQ.png

[image]

Could someone explain what exactly this definition is saying and give a simple example?

It seems like it's saying given a finite list of $n$ elements, $n-1$ of them are; equal, or in the previous relation in some order.  But this doesn't seem to make sense.

As an example:

$X = \{1,2,3, 4\}$ with less than relation $R = \{(1,2), (1,3), (2,3), (2,4), (3,4)\}$,

what would be an example of $R'$?

Comment: It is a sort of *path* "connecting" $x$ and $y$ through $R$. We say that $xR'y$ if there is some $R$-*path* connecting them.

Comment: In your example, $1$ is "connected" to $2$ and $3$ and $4$ (by way of $(1,2)$ and $(2,4)$). This $R'$ defines a single equiv class $[ 1 ]_R = \{ 1,2,3,4 \}$.

Comment: The image link is dead.

Comment: A direct link to the image has been added in the question.

Comment: In addition to the path, we have also $1R'1$ because with $n=1$ the def allows us to have $x_0=x, x_1=y$ and $x_0=x_1$.

Answer (score 0):

It is stated that $R^\prime$ derived from $R$ via the given rules is an *[equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation)*. So we can check if *reflexivity*, *symmetry* and *transitivity* is provided by these rules.

> - *Reflexivity:*
>
>   With $(x,y)\in R$ we obtain $(x,x)\in R'$ and $(y,y)\in R'$ since we can apply $x_i=x_{i+1}$ with $i=0$. This way it is assured that all elements of the *diagonal* are elements of $R'$. $$\{(x,x)|x\in X\}\subseteq R'$$
> - *Symmetry:*
>
>   Whenever $(x,y)\in R'$ we also need $(y,x)\in R'$. This is assured by the rules $(x_i,x_{i+1})\in R$ or $(x_{i+1},x_i)\in R$.
> - *Transitivity:*
>
>   Is given by the two rules to obtain symmetry and reflexivity above together with the chaining of the elements with index range $0\leq i\leq n-1$.